# GLPaint Version 1.12 shake gesture doesn't work

Tags: iphone, shake

In the newly released GLPaint sample code from Apple seems to be an error: the shake event doesn't work. But i can't find the reason, even after looking up nearly every thread about shake events in this forum.
i am really going crazy because i don't see anything wrong in the code.

EDIT:
I thought i would have come closer (but it still doesn't work) by changing following things:
In AppController.h change UIWindow to "PaintingWindow". Also the .xib file, i changed the class to PaintingWindow. Another thing is, i overwrote the function canBecomeFirstResponder in PaintingWindow.m with return YES. Furthermore i added in applicationDidFinishLaunching, that the window becomes first responder.

So changed a lot, nothing worked. Please someone?